# Using AssembliesFromPath from StructureMap throws MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap, structuremap4

I am trying to scan all assemblies in a subfolder of my main project and then add the contained registry to my main registry in order to override default registry entries, where necessary and intercept types for dependency injection.

For this I create the following registry

```
public PluginRegistryAdder(string pluginPath)
{
    Scan(x =>
    {
        x.AssembliesFromPath(pluginPath);
        x.LookForRegistries();
    });
}
```

which I plan to add to my main container like this:

```
 var pluginRegistries = new PluginRegistryAdder(pluginPath);
 Container.Configure(_ => _.IncludeRegistry(pluginRegistries));
```

The problem I am now facing is that I get this error, when using `AssembliesFromPath` and I don't know how to fix it:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void StructureMap.Graph.IAssemblyScanner.AssembliesFromPath(System.String)'.

Googling suggests that I should use the namespace `StructureMap.Graph`, but this did not solve the problem. Here are my using statements, of which only `StructureMap` is not greyed out (e.g. marked as not redundant) by Visual Studio (I was trying to find the missing reference, but nothing helped):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using StructureMap;
using StructureMap.Graph;
using StructureMap.Configuration.DSL;
using StructureMap.Configuration;
using StructureMap.Graph.Scanning;
using StructureMap.Util;
```

Any suggestions, what I should try?!

**UPDATES:**

1. Note that when I comment out just the line with `AssembliesFromPath`, solution runs just fine, although `LookForRegistries` is definded in the same class as `AssembliesFromPath`.
2. `AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory` gives me the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to have been caused by a version mismatch between my DI project and my main project. After some trying I ended up reinstalling the newest version of StructureMap in *both* projects and the problem went away.